# Looping over a vector to uiOutput() always prints the first element of the vector to the app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a vector:

```
   filter_vars <- c("source", "medium", "campaign", "userType", "deviceCategory", "Condition",
                    "Voice", "Format", "Type", "Stage_Topic"),
```

Within my Shiny app UI, for each vector I would like to create a `uiOutput()`

```
   # output the filters  
   box(width = 3,
       title = "Filters",
       lapply(filter_vars, function(x) uiOutput(x))
    ),
```

This works, my app displays all of the ui filter boxes.

However, the first element in the vector is always displayed! See screen shot, where "source", the first item in the vector is displayed right above the filters:
[image]

I experimented with changing my loop

```
lapply(filter_vars, function(x) uiOutput(x[[1]]))
```

However no change. Why is R Shiny displaying the string "source"? What should I do to prevent this?

Here is code to replicate using iris dataset, where "Sepal.Length" will unexpectedly display like "source" did above:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("My Shiny App"),

   # row with filters
   fluidRow(style = "border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
                      margin-bottom: 10px",

   filter_vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"),


   # output the filters  
   box(width = 3,
       title = "Filters",
       lapply(filter_vars, function(x) uiOutput(x))
    )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    # drop down of uniques to pass to ui
  filter_vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")

  outputFilters <- function(id, df) {
    output[[id]] <- renderUI({
     selectInput(id, 
                 label = id, 
                 choices = as.list(c(paste0("All ", id, "s"), unique(df[[id]]))),
                 selected = paste0("All ", id, "s"))
      })
  }

  lapply(filter_vars, function(x) outputFilters(x, iris))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code to check?

Comment: How about this - `filter_vars <- c("",filter_vars)`?

Comment: @amrrs yes sorry, added reproducible example now based on iris dd

Comment: @Prem thanks for the tip, think I'll use that as back up plan!

Comment: @DougFir No problem. Please check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the position of `filter_vars` which when mentioned inside ui would make shiny consider it's just another ui element. Taking the vector creation out of UI fixes the issue.

```
library(shiny)

filter_vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),

  # row with filters
  fluidRow(style = "border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
           margin-bottom: 10px",



           # output the filters  
           box(width = 3,
               title = "Filters",
               lapply(filter_vars, function(x) uiOutput(x))
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # drop down of uniques to pass to ui
  filter_vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")

  outputFilters <- function(id, df) {
    output[[id]] <- renderUI({
      selectInput(id, 
                  label = id, 
                  choices = as.list(c(paste0("All ", id, "s"), unique(df[[id]]))),
                  selected = paste0("All ", id, "s"))
    })
  }

  lapply(filter_vars, function(x) outputFilters(x, iris))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```